# Component data was gone after re rendering, even though Component was react.memo already

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have two components.

First is called: BucketTabs

Second is called:BucketForms

To have a better idea. Below pictures illustrate it.
When I switching tab, different form will be showed below.

[image]

Q: Whenever I switch from one tab to other tab, and then switch back, the content in the previous BucketForms will be gone. But, gone data are supposed to be stored into a state of that BucketForms.

In fact, I've memo the BucketForms already, so I've expected the content(data) would not be gone.

What's the problem and how could I prevent the data to be gone after switching tab.

My BucketTabs:

```
import { BucketForms } from '~components/BucketForms/BuckForms'

export const BucketTabs: React.FC = () => {
 

  const items = useMemo<ContentTabsItem[]>((): ContentTabsItem[] => {
    return [
      {
        title: '1',
        renderContent: () => <BucketForms key="1" bucketCategory="1" />,
      },
      {
        title: '2',
        renderContent: () => <BucketForms key="2" bucketCategory="2" />,
      },
    ]
  }, [])

 

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col">
        <ContentTabs items={tabs} kind="tabs" />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

BucketForms

```
function PropsAreEqual(prev, next) {
  const result = prev.bucketCategory === next.bucketCategory;
  return result;
}

interface IData {
  portfolioValue?: number
  }
export const BucketForms: React.FC<IProps> = React.memo(props => {
  const { bucketCategory } = props
  const [data, setData] = useState<IData>({
  })

  
  const view = ({
    portfolioValue,
  }: IData) => {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="row portfolio">
          <FormNumericInput
            key="input-portfolio-value"
            name="portfolioValue"
            required
            value={portfolioValue}
          />
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }


  return (
  <Form
      onChange={e => {
        setData({ ...data, ...e, })
      }}
    >
      {view(data)}
   </Form>
  )
}, PropsAreEqual)
```

Comment: That's not the question here,  why did the data in my child was gone?

Comment: but the data in my child is store inside a state, it is not sth will be re created. data is crerated by state. So, after a rendering, data inside should be still here right. it is a state, not a simple variable

Comment: my useMemo here is intended to memo the componment, so it wont get rendered a new one.

Comment: Please share the code for `ContentTabs`. It looks like it renders the selected tab but unmounts the other unselected one. So it is not surprising all the state will be lost when you switch tabs. Unless, you have state stored somewhere up in the tree or in a store such as Redux.

Comment: ContentTabs is a library , ...

Comment: Which lib? Maybe google if that lib allows using `display:none` instead of umounting hidden tabs. Otherwise I am afraid you either have to move the sate up manually or switch to a different lib more suitable to your use case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After a render of not showing a child, the child state data was gone completely when it render again. Why's that and how to prevent it happening?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73330377/after-a-render-of-not-showing-a-child-the-child-state-data-was-gone-completely)

Comment: The library is only allowed to stick with this such use case.

Comment: For previous question, it answered why it cant prevent it from not losting data.  But for this question, since its more complicated, so thanks for trying

Comment: Btw, I come from background of functional componment, may I ask where I can get a good study guide about a comprehensive umounting concept?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247225/discussion-between-irfanullah-jan-and-ae-leung).