# After a render of not showing a child, the child state data was gone completely when it render again. Why's that and how to prevent it happening?

Tags: reactjs

In my parent component, there is a button to control whether to show the child or not.

In the input box, the input value is stored inside child component. When value is input, everything seem fine, data is recorded very fine in the child's state.

1.
[image]

2. click to not show it
   [image]
3. click to show again
   [image]

Child's input box value was gone, and the state value in child was gone as well.

How can I keep the value when I click to show the child again?

In parent:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Child1 from "./child";

import "./styles.css";

function Parent() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("initial text");
  const [showChild,setShowChild] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useeffect in parent");
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setShowChild(!showChild)}>show child</button>
      {showChild? 
      <Child1 />
      :
      null
      
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, rootElement);
```

In child:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function Child1() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useeffect in child");
    console.log("newMessage: " + newMessage);
  });
  const [newMessage, setNewMessage] = useState("");


  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={(event) => setNewMessage(event.target.value)} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Child1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are conditionally rendering `<Child1 />` which means that when you click the toggle again to hide it, React basically unmounts it i.e. it is removed completely from the tree and thus all component state is lost. When you click the toggle again to show the component, it is mounted again.

One way to fix this would be to set `show` prop on the component itself and let it manage how it is shown and hidden. For example:

In parent:

```js
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setShowChild(!showChild)}>show child</button>
      <Child1 show={showChild} />
    </div>
  );
```

In child:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function Child1(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useeffect in child");
    console.log("newMessage: " + newMessage);
  });
  const [newMessage, setNewMessage] = useState("");

  if (!props.show) return <React.Fragment />

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={(event) => setNewMessage(event.target.value)} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Child1;
```

Inside child, you may alternatively use the prop `show` to set CSS style  `display:none` on `div` when `show` is false. This ways the input element itself with remain in the DOM but is simply hidden.

So instead of returning `<React.Fragment />` we would modify the return statement as follows:

```js
return (
  <div style={props.show ? null : {display: "none"}}>
    <input onChange={(event) => setNewMessage(event.target.value)} />
  </div>
);
```

As a third option, you can "elevate the state" meaning that you move `newMessage` state up to parent and pass `newMessage` and `setNewMessage` down to child as props, and keep the rest of the code how it is in your question.

In parent:

```js
const [newMessage, setNewMessage] = useState("");
...
return (
  ...
  <Child1 newMessage={newMessage} setNewMessage={setNewMessage} />
  ...
)
```

In child:

```js
const {newMessage, setNewMessage} = props;
```

Comment: If it is possible that I use React.memo or memo the child, so that in case the child needs to render again, it would give me back the previous one with original one, but not creating me a whole new one

Comment: Memo won't help to remember state when a component unmounts. But as another alternative, you may also want to move the `newMessage` state to parent and pass the value and setter down to child via props.

Comment: In fact, this question is my simplication of my original question. The thing is i am not able to pass the control of showing or not to the child. Plus, the library of parent seems to somehow was fixed to control it on his own. Could you pls take a look of this problem and suggest ways? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73324425/component-data-was-gone-after-re-rendering-even-though-component-was-react-memo

Comment: would you mind upvoting this question? since this edge problem may sound confusing to others too.

Comment: btw , may i ask what is the difference between return <React.Fragment /> and return (<></>)   [sometimes we have to put  () after return, but sometimes we need not to put any () ]

Comment: There is not much difference, but if for some reason we need to pass `key` prop, we have to use `<React.Fragment key={} />` we can't do `< key={}></>`

Comment: thanks, speaking of key, may I ask why we have to put "key " sometimes? I noticed that sometimes if we dont put "key".... react will only render one component if we have multiple same components to fire in the code

Comment: This explains it pretty clearly https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/8z7lju/when_does_a_component_unmount/

I also find this is helpful

If the condition changes from true to false, then the new pass of rendering does not include child, and so the prior one will unmount.